# find the minimal polynomial of the following over the Rationals

Tags: ring-theory

Find the  minimal polynomial of the following numbers over $\mathbb Q$:
$\sqrt 5-2\sqrt 3$

and the other problem is
$\sqrt{\sqrt[3]2{-i}}$

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha:=\sqrt5-2\sqrt3$, we can state the following:
$$(\alpha+2\sqrt3)^2=5\,.$$
So, $\alpha^2+4\sqrt3\alpha+4\cdot 3=5$, that is,
$$\alpha^2+7=-4\sqrt3\alpha$$
Now square it again to obtain a rational equation that $\alpha$ satisfies.

Try similar method for $\beta:=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]2-i}$.